# How to Open document in UserControl using Process.Start()

Tags: wpf, popup, webbrowser-control, process.start

> Currently I have used `Process.Start(documentUrl)` in the WPF application
>   to open document.It opens document in a new window.I have one user
>   control.That User Control is displayed in one of the Dockpanel of the
>   main window.So when I select some document I want to open that
>   document in that User control.Is it possible?
>
> I have also used WebBrowser inside the User Control but since it is
>   not a WPF control.It is displayed in the top layer.Due to which all
>   the PopUp are displayed behind that User control.So WebBrowser is of
>   no use to me.
>
> Kindly suggest any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should have googled your issue first before asking here.

However here are few links for you. It seems you are looking for Flow Document control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners

Comment: I have googled it.But dint get any useful info so i posted question here.I will check these links.Thanks